# MySQL querying a name that's across two columns

Tags: mysql

I need to make an MySQL query where I only have a full name available. for example "John Doe" But in my database I have two columns, first_name and last_name and the names are split across these two columns. So If i wanted to query I would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name='John' AND last_name='Doe'
```

I tried splitting the name with the spaces and then build a query like above. But problem is that some names are double barrel. Is there any way to make a query in MySQL where I could query where combined two columns equals John Doe?

Comment: You should include material and concrete examples of when your solution failed. It may be that improving the logic of parsing your input will yield the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select * from users
where concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) = 'John Doe';
```

Comment: Should note that by doing this any possibility of an index seek is likely replaced with a scan.  This may or may not be an issue to the OP, but is a potentially profound consequence of such a pattern.

Comment: @MatBailie thanks, I'm not as familiar with MySQL as I am PostgreSQL. Can you create an index in MySQL that would work with this?

Comment: MySQL 8 supports computed columns (called generated columns), which can be indexed. The OP hasn't specified if it's MySQL 8 or 5.x